# Update Value of Angular Reactive Form disabled field based on other Form Controls

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

I am using Reactive Forms in Angular and have a disabled Form Control that is calculated based on the values of the other fields/Form Controls.  How can I update the value of that disabled field as the value of it's dependent fields changes.  The calculation is working but I need it to subscribe to the other field's changes.  My function that creates the FormGroup looks like this:

```
createBasket(basket: any) {
    return new FormGroup({
      length: new FormControl(basket.length),
      width: new FormControl(basket.width),
      height: new FormControl(basket.height),
      crossSectArea: new FormControl({value: basket.length * basket.width * basket.height, disabled: true}, Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

Not sure if this would change the solution, but I am also using FormArray to create an array of the Form Group instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`FormControl API`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) exposes a [`valueChanges` observable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) which you can subscribe to and then use the [`setValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue) method to imperatively set the value of the other form control in the subscribe block:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.basketForm = createBasket(basket);
  const length = this.basketForm.get('length');
  const width = this.basketForm.get('width');
  length.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    width.setValue(val * 2);
  });
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/interdependent-form-controls.

Comment: Thanks vincecampanale for the detailed answer.  I am using Custom Validator elsewhere, I just felt like there has to be a simpler solution to my issue as I don't need to validate any fields, I just need to update the value (calculation) of a field when the other changes.

Comment: I totally misread your question the first time, my bad! Updated my answer so it actually answers your question.

Comment: Haha, no worries thanks!  My only question is how to implement this within a FormArray?

Comment: Happy to help, I'm not sure how to answer your question based on the code you provided. If you want to set the value of a control in an array you can use the `setControl` on the `FormArray`. If you want to set the value of the array you can use the `setValue` method as I showed above. If the group you showed in the question is the member of an array, you can iterate through that array and use the approach I mentioned. It depends on your code and what you're trying to do, but this general combo of `valueChanges` and `setValue` will do the trick in any case.

Comment: Here's a link to the `FormArray` API docs for good measure: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray. Does that information help?